# How to remove the default border around a group of subitems?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to find a way to get rid of the border around the container of the MenuItems of a menu, in Expression Blend 4.

Here is an image of what I mean, I'd like to make the big white border around Item2 and Item3 disappear.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhOwY.png

And here is the XAML of this menu:

```
<Menu Background="{DynamicResource MenuGradient}" Margin="8,3,0,0" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GeneratedMenuItem}">
    <MenuItem x:Name="itm1" Header="Item1" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Template="{DynamicResource CustomMenuItemStyle}">
        <MenuItem x:Name="itm2" Header="Item2" Style="{DynamicResource CustomSubMenuItemStyle}"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="itm3" Header="Item3" Style="{DynamicResource CustomSubMenuItemStyle}"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="itmOptions" Header="Options" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Template="{DynamicResource CustomMenuItemStyle}"/>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to edit the popup part inside the template of the menu item.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Actually, I needed to remove the Chrome shadow and replace it by its Grid child. The border was owned by the "Shdw" of the PART_Popup of the MenuItem.